# Sync Framework How To Deploy

Tags: c#, .net, installation, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I want to create client application with synchronization function. It will be use the MS Sync Framework (sync files with server). How to deploy Sync Framework with my application. Just include dll?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include all sync dll references. I have a SQL 2008 database syncing with a Compact 3.5 clients, for this setup. Skip project deployment prerequisites and go to application files on your deployment project's properties.

and include:

```
Microsoft.Synchronization 
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe
```

If you are not using SqlServerCe include the appropriate dll. I think if you are using sqlexpress you will need to add that as a prerequisite.